# Symfony forms high memory

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have some somewhat complex forms in my Symfony app which I use for handling data in my API through the FOSRestBundle.

In some cases I have 10-15 nested child forms, some of them are collections which  have 20 or so records.

When I submit one of these forms, memory spikes up a few hundred mb, and I can't work out why.

Here is an example of one of the forms - all the child forms are no different.

There is nothing complex happening here, so I can't work out why a few kb of JSON takes a few hundred Mb to process.

Where am I going wrong?

```
class SomeForm extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('field-a')
            ->add('field-b')
            ->add('field-c')
            ->add('field-d', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new AnotherForm1(),
                'allow_add' => true
                )
            )
            ->add('field-d', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new AnotherForm2(),
                'allow_add' => true
            ));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                                   'data_class'      => 'My\Bundle\Entity\SomeEntity',
                                   'csrf_protection' => false,
                               ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'SomeForm';
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I am having the same problem..when I use 'allow_add'  the thing just blows up

Comment: No sorry, I ended up scrapping the forms component completely, partly because of this problem, and partly because it sets all empty strings to null. I was only using it for a REST API so a combination of the JMS serializer and the Symfony validation component with sufficient for my needs. Good luck.

Comment: gotcha, I think I found a "solution"... this is happening to me when I have a third child that has a property that is actually an entity..for example SingleConcert->Band->Members[]->Member->Instrument(entity)

so if in this case I remove the Instrument property everything works properly, but if I try to use the api to send the instrument everything blows up.. I am pretty sure that Data Transformer would solve this but I am trying to think of something else since I am not very fond of Data Transformers

Comment: Just as I thought, you just need to have any sub entity that will NOT be created along with the parent entity have a data transformer and have that field as a simple text type, let me know if you want me to provide a more detailed answer but I got this working :)!

Answer (score 0):

Is this just in the dev environment or on the prod environment?  If it is dev, it's probably the logger that is causing the massive memory spike as it is logging the loading actions for all the objects in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think I will leave this here in case it helps anyone. Lets assume I had the following structure:

```
+ Dealer
  - Name [String]
  + Car [Collection]
    - NumberOfSeats [Int]
    + Manufacturer[Entity] 
      - Name
      - Phone
      - ..etc..
```

The problem that I was facing was that if I define my form normally following instructions I would end up with something like this:

**DealerType**

```
   /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('cars', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => CarType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'by_reference' => false,

            ))
        ;
    }
```

**CarType**

```
   /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('numberOfSeats', TextType::class)
            ->add('manufacturer', ManufacturerType::class)
        ;
    }
```

**ManufacturerType**

```
/**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('phone', TextType::class)            
        ;
    }
```

3 pretty simple forms. However, lets say that by REST you want to do the following in the action handling the POST:

```
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    $car = new Car();
    /** @var FormInterface $form */
    $form = $this->createForm(CarType::class, $car);
    $form->submit($data);
```

And lets assume that you are sending something like :

```
{ "name": "DealerA", "cars": [{"numberOfSeats": 2, "manufacturer": {"id": 1, "name": "ExistingManufacturer", "phone": "1234567"}}]}
```

If you would like to pass an existing manufacturer (hence the id in a POST request) I thought that Symfony2 would just grab the ID and figure out that the manufacturer already existed and it would've match up the relationship bla bla bla. However, this was not the case. I experienced a bunch of "Memory allowed exceded" errors, I still do not know the relationship on this and I think that it might be that SF2 finds itself in some sort of loop or something if you try to provide the ID of a child entity if the parent entity is not even created yet.

In short: if it's a subentity that already exists and you are CREATING (POST) and not updating (PUT) SF2 will throw the server down due to memory consumption

**Solution: Data Transformer**

What I thought was that, if what I was trying to get in the database was an existing entity, I didn't really have the need to pass the entire subentity, I just need to pass some sort of reference to the form so that it handles the relationship. This is where I thought about data transformers, if I pass just the name of the manufacturer (instead of "manufacturer": { "name": "..", "phone": "..." } i should only have to do "manufacturer": ".."). The only "downside" is that via the POST/PUT I won't be able to modify the content of that subentity. but again, if the entity is a ManyToOne(Many Cars can have the same Manufacturer) I don't see the point on modifying the Manufacturer when Creating/Updating a Car. For this we usually create a separate manufacturer section.

In case that the relationship was OneToOne or OneToMany then this fix should not be needed.

**ManufacturerNameToIdTransformer**

Basically following [Symfony2 Data Transformer Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) you can get a simple data transformer to transform a manufacturer name to a Manufacturer entity and vice versa, then you would change the CarType to the following:

```
    /**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('numberOfSeats', TextType::class)
        ->add('manufacturer', TextType::class)            
    ;

    $builder->get('manufacturer')->addModelTransformer(new ManufacturerNameToId($this->em));
}
```

As you can see I now use a TextType for the manufacturer and the REST request would now look something like this:

```
{ "name": "DealerA", "cars": [{"numberOfSeats": 2, "manufacturer": "ExistingManufacturerName"}]}
```

Voila!, now it makes kind of more sense for a ManyToOne relationship and SF2 doesn't hang when creating a new entity.

Hope it helps someone since I wasted half a day on this lol.